# Java 8 Lambda: Map List<Object[]> (List of Object Arrays) to List<Bean>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I receive a List of Object arrays,

```
List<Object[]> rawRows = service.getRows();
```

Any particular value can be obtained as e.g.

```
(Date)((Object[])rawRows.get(i))[3]  // In each item, Array Element #3 is a certain Date
```

I need to map this to a `List<Report>` for a POJO which has specific fields defined for each value:

```
public class Report {
    private String abbreviation;
    private String username;
    private Integer recallid;
    private Date recalldate;
    // ... + getters/setters   

    // Constructor
    public Report (String abbreviation, String username, Integer recallid, Date recalldate, ...)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm stumped on the following: How would I specify the **index** in this Lamba expression to map to my new `List<Report>`?

```
List<Report> detailReports =  rawRows.stream().map(obj -> new Report(
            (String)((Object[])rawRows.get(0))[0], // I'm hard-coding (0) but need "i"
            (String)((Object[])rawRows.get(0))[1], // I'm hard-coding (0) but need "i"
            (Integer)((Object[])rawRows.get(0))[2],// I'm hard-coding (0) but need "i"
            (Date)((Object[])rawRows.get(0))[3],   // I'm hard-coding (0) but need "i"
            //...
                           )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My goal is to have a `List<Report>` with all the array elements mapped to the POJO per object exactly per the specified sequence. But there's no `i` index for me to track. In this example I'm hard-coding `0` as the `rawRow` to get from the original List.

Comment: I think you are doing wrong, you should use `obj` in lambda expression `(String) obj[0]`

Comment: The idea of functional programming is to keep your lambda(function) stateless. i.e., it should not depend on an external variable i to determine what the value is. As Deadpool mentioned, `obj` gives you enough to achieve the desired value

Comment: thanks it should have been obj[i] as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change your lambda from

```
obj -> new Report((String)((Object[])rawRows.get(0))[0] ...
```

to

```
obj -> new Report((String) obj[0] ...
```

`obj` is the lambda parameter, and in the `map()` function will take on the value of each item in `rawRows`.

Next, I would really recommend converting the lambda into a separate, named function. This would have signature `public Report rawRowToReport(Object[] rawRow)` and would hold all your indexing logic, instead of writing it in the lambda body.

The reason for this is, as you've noticed, *"there's no `i` index for me to track"*: this is because the indexing being done by `i` is into the raw row itself. It's really just the [*deserialization logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) for whatever is in the `Object[]`. This sort of logic should be encapsulated in its own method (or ideally class) which only deals with serializing and/or deserializing. Outside users (like your `Stream`) delegate the nitty gritty to that class or method. Ultimately, the `Stream` only handles the process of iterating over the data and applying filters and transforms. It doesn't know what those filters and transforms require.

```
rawRows.stream().map(this::rawRowToReport).collect(Collectors.toList());
```